# How can I let Javascript know when I select an option value?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a list of option values that, when they are selected, I want to pass information to Javascript, so that I can try to have Javascript contact the server and update several other fields based on that option value (AJAX - something I'm new to!)

How do I let Javascript know that I selected a particular option value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind a change event listener to the `select` element (this assumes your `select` element has an `id` of `yourSelect`):

```
document.getElementById("yourSelect").onchange = function() {
    var selected = this.value;
    //Do whatever with the selected value
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/dnBGC/). The `onchange` event listener is called whenever the value of the `select` changes. You can access the `value` of the selected option with `this.value`, and pass that to your server side script.

Answer (score 0):

In ugly direct-coding methods:

```
<select onchange="the_select_was_changed(this);">
     <option>...</option>
     <option>...</option>
</select>

function the_select_was_changed(obj) {
    alert("The selected index is " + obj.selectedIndex + " and has value " + obj.options[obj.selectedIndex]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add for each selectboxes the event onChange:

```
<select name="{any name}" onChange="myVJsValuecheckFunction(this)">
  <option value="{myOptionValueOne}">myoptionText</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Then write the javascript function:

```
function
```